# (React-Native) Manifest is not a valid JSONObject or JSONArray

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-thunk

I am using expo for react-native development i want to use redux and redux-thunk in my react native application for that i create project using command `expo init myproject` and after that
`cd myproject`.

Now when i run `expo start` command it build successfuly and run as it was supposed to be.

Then to install redux i use 'npm install redux redux-thunk react-redux'.

When I use the same command `expo start` to run myproject and run it on my android emulator i got.[image]

And that in my emulator[image]

When I open error log i got [image]

Can anyone please help?